# Remove cancel button in ABPeoplePickerNavigationController. Strange behavior in iOs 4.x

Tags: iphone, ios4, uinavigationcontroller, uibarbuttonitem, abpeoplepickerview

I would like to remove the cancel button in the navigation bar of ABPeoplePickerNavigationController because I want to have an add button.
I customized the navigation controller delegate in this way:

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated{


switch ([navigationController.viewControllers count]) {

    case 0: {

        viewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil;
        break;

    }

    case 1: {

        viewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil;
        break;
    }

    case 2: {



        UIBarButtonItem *addButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(addPerson:)];
        [viewController.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:addButtonItem animated:NO];
        [addButtonItem release];



        UIBarButtonItem *cancelButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self action:@selector(cancel:)];
        [viewController.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:cancelButtonItem animated:NO];
        [cancelButtonItem release];



        NSLog(@"View 2 %@",viewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem);


        break;
    }
    case 3: {

             UIBarButtonItem *editButtonItem;

             if ([viewController isKindOfClass:[ABPersonViewController class]]) {    

                    editButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemEdit target:self action:@selector(editPerson:)];
                    self.personView  = (ABPersonViewController*) viewController;
                    self.personView.allowsEditing = YES;
                    self.personView.personViewDelegate = self;
                    [viewController.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:editButtonItem animated:NO];
                    [editButtonItem release];

            } else {
         // ABPersonNewViewController
        //No need to add codes here
            }  

           break;
    }

    default: {




        break;
    }

}
```

It works fine in iOs 3.x and iOs 5.x, but in iOS 4.x I always have the cancel button in the navigation bar when the contacts list appears but if I select a contact then I go back to the first view controller the add button will appear.

How can explain this strange behavior only in iOS 4.x ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {


NSLog(@"Contacts view did appear");

[super viewDidLoad];
picker = [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc]init];
[picker setDelegate:self];
[picker setAllowsCancel:NO];

self.picker.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
```

}

So if you want to remove the cancel button in iOs 4.x you have to add this line:
[picker setAllowsCancel:NO];
I received a warning from the compiler, but now the cancel button is removed in iOS 4.x

Answer (score 0):

```
[picker setAllowsCancel:NO];
```

//picker is an object of ABPeoplePickerNavigationController.